# Python secrets.randbits takes forever once increased above 16

Tags: python, cryptography

I have been trying to implement [the Fermat Test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUMotDWVLpw) in a python script to generate a large prime number, and I was hoping to use it on big primes, and it works quickly and almost perfectly for 16 bit generations, but if I set it to 32 it just doesn't run at all.

For quick context, the Fermat test is supposed to run x amount of trials (set to 5 in my code just so I can see if it works, but in use I would probably set it higher to ~20 or something) to test if a number is prime or not. So I am generating large numbers using secrets.randbits then checking them with the Fermat test to see if they are prime, and if they are not I pick a different prime and run it again until I find one.

With bits set to 16, the code runs quickly, printing many different numbers to the logs that are tested before finding out they are composite and choosing a different one, but once set to 32 nothing is printed at all, and I really have no idea why. Does secrets.randbits only work/take exponentially longer for increased bits, because at 16 bits the program runs almost instantaneously, but it doesn't seem to work at all at 32.

Here is my code:

```
import secrets 
import math

def fermat_test(n): # this is the correct algorithm from the video and it works set at 16 bits
    for x in range(1, 5): # to run 5 trials
        if (pow(secrets.randbelow(n - 1) + 1, (n - 1)) % n) != 1: 
            return False
    return True

bits = 16 # changing this to 32 the program will seemingly idle, not printing anything to console
rand = secrets.randbits(bits)
while (not fermat_test(rand)): # while the number is not prime
    print(rand) # prints the number being checked
    rand = secrets.randbits(bits)
print(rand)
```

sorry if this was too convoluted I can try editing it to reword everything if it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news:  this has nothing to do with `secrets`.  Change this:

```
        if (pow(secrets.randbelow(n - 1) + 1, (n - 1)) % n) != 1:
```

to this:

```
        if pow(secrets.randbelow(n - 1) + 1, (n - 1), n) != 1:
```

3-argument `pow()` computes modular exponentiation very efficiently. What you wrote instead creates a giant integer (you're basically raising a 32-bit integer to a 32-bit power - the result will run into *billions* of decimal digits), and only *then* doing a modulus operation.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, it runs so quickly now! Sorry I can't upvote your answer since I don't have enough reputation but just thank you so much again.